# How to redirect output from file to stdout?

Tags: command-line

I'd like to rip the titles from a bunch of word documents. All the CLI tools I've tried for converting .doc to text lose the title... but Abiword's conversion to RTF preserves it, eg:

```
$ abiword --to=rtf something.doc
```

gives *something.rtf*, a text-encoded file that includes the title.

So far so good but I need one line of the file, writing it seems very wasteful. (eg if I could get the output to go to stdout, I'd run this with Python's subprocess, capture it and apply a regex to get a list of titles).

But, unless I'm missing something, Abiword CLI tool doesn't seem to be set up to output to standard out. You can either:

- specify output format, giving original file name + new extension, or
- specify filename; Abiword infers file type from the extension.

**Is there a way to get around this, and just get the output via stdout?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example in the `abiword` man page:

```
abiword --to=rtf --to-name=fd://1 something.doc
```

Comment: I wonder whether `--to-name=/dev/stdout` would work.  P.S. It may be possible to use `-o` instead of `--to-name`.

Comment: I tried that: `AbiWord: Uch! Could not write the file [/dev/stdout]`

Answer (score 1):

-o works without the '=', eg:

*abiword --to=rtf -o fd://1 something.doc*