# How to redirect output to file to STDOUT?

Tags: shell, command-line, io-redirection, tcsh

Similar problem as here
[How to redirect output from file to stdout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196211/how-to-redirect-output-from-file-to-stdout)
However, the solution given there is not universal.

*My problem:* I have a command that produces output to STDOUT. At the same time, I can specify via arguments to produce another output that goes straight to a file.

```
tcsh$ hmmscan --domtblout FILEOUTPUT Pfam-A.hmm query.fasta
```

Pfam-A.hmm is a database file (input); query.fasta is also an input file

**How can I redirect FILEOUTPUT to STDOUT ?**

*Background:* I plan to use the command on thousands of inputs and I need to run it for each of them separately. The command is called within a Python script, and I would like to read its FILEOUTPUT directly into the memory/a variable using the subprocess module. I know how to get the STDOUT with the subprocess module; so if I could redirect FILEOUTPUT to STDOUT...

I tried already stuff like this (ended up with errors or created files):

```
tcsh$ hmmscan --domtblout >/dev/tty Pfam-A.hmm query.fasta
tcsh$ hmmscan --domtblout >(mypipe) Pfam-A.hmm query.fasta
tcsh$ hmmscan --domtblout >$ Pfam-A.hmm query.fasta
tcsh$ hmmscan --domtblout >($1) Pfam-A.hmm query.fasta
tcsh$ hmmscan --domtblout >cat Pfam-A.hmm query.fasta
tcsh$ hmmscan --domtblout test.tab Pfam-A.hmm query.fasta >/dev/tty
```

Comment: there's a `tcsh` in your prompt string; does the solution need to work in tcsh, or were those just sample runs, while your code would be called from python (to /bin/sh, presumably)?

Answer (score 3):

To make the hmmscan program write to stdout instead of a regular file, specify `/dev/stdout` instead of the regular filename.  e.g.

```
$ hmmscan --domtblout /dev/stdout Pfam-A.hmm query.fasta
```